# Can the Address field of different PCI devices of MSI Capability be same?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt, pci, pci-e

I am working on an arm64 based board, running on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). On the other end of this device, there is an FPGA connected via PCIe which is endpoint and arm based board is root complex. I have written driver for that.
The FPGA seems to be generating the MSI interrupt, but somehow the arm board is not receiving it. FPGA writes MSI data to 0x00000000fffff000 address. Bus mastering is also enabled.
I checked /proc/interrupts file on arm board, and it seems to be registering the interrupt successfully with an appropriate IRQ number, which can also be seen in output of lspci -vvv.
There is a WiFi card connected to another PCIe port.
MSI Capabilities are displayed as follows for both (WiFi card and FPGA).

FPGA:

```
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fffff000  Data: 0000
```

WiFi card:

```
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fffff000  Data: 0000
```

My question is, can both the devices have same value in their "Address" field. IRQ numbers are different for both the devices and are not being shared with anything else. I confirmed it from /proc/interrupts file. If they have the same address, how the interrupt handler I have written in my driver will get called? That is, how interrupt will get routed to the IRQ number that is registered to be used with my driver?

Comment: I don't know enough about ARM to answer your question, but I believe that on ARM (unlike on Intel systems) MSIs are processed by DMA remapping in the IOMMU. So the same address written to by different devices may be mapped to different physical addresses and result in different interrupts being delivered.

Comment: @prl There are many ARM platforms having no IOMMU integrated.

Comment: @prl I think the address shown is the physical one, its a special address to which the endpoint device will write the data which will trigger the interrupt.

Comment: @ChenLi This board has IOMMU. Its called SMMU (System MMU).

Comment: The addresses for MSI are important for GIC controllers. As far as GIC can distinguish the source of IRQ and on CPU side is possible to find that source -- everything is fine. But I also think that MSI represents as a physical address in RAM where DMA can write. So, it's possible to have the same address, but it will be a disaster to the system if there is no additional layer of mapping present.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for that. I checked the code and found dma_alloc_coherent is used for mapping the MSI address.